# How to create a navbar with fixed item positions in sm-md sizes in Bootstrap4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achive a navbar that keeps its proportions in sm and md column sizes.I want to achive a navbar like in nm.org with fixed proportions no matter the size of the viewport.

I did try the row-columns display and the different options for column extension in the different contexts, but the toggle button keeps jumping to the next line... I want to rely on bt4 classes as much as possible. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: add your code so we can see what is wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all. I just did the trick by controlling the appearance in all contexts using media queries.

Answer (score -2):

Please Try this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">YouLogo</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">2nd Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<script>
    (function($){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= 250){
                $('nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            }else{
                $('nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Shoaib, thank you for your answer. I tried, It did not work, I think if we replace the event instead of scroll to resizing -I mean the appropiate event for the document resizing-, it could work. I will try and let you know.